# (Proof Verification) The necessary and sufficient condition for $X:\mathbb{T}\times\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be a stochastic process.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, solution-verification, stochastic-analysis

Recall that a stochastic process $\{X_{t}:t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ leads to the mapping $\xi:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ which maps an outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ to the corresponding trajectory of the process, namely $\{t\mapsto X_{t}(\omega)\}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}.$

Define the elementary cylinder as $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:x_{t_{1}}\in B_{1},\cdots, x_{t_{n}}\in B_{n}\},$$ for some $B_{1},\cdots, B_{n}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Then, define the cylindrical $\sigma-$algebra by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}):=\sigma(\text{elementary cylinders}).$

Now, I'd like to show that

> $X:\mathbb{T}\times\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a stochastic process if and only if $X$ seen as  $X:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}))-$measurable.

I showed the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ without problem, I "kind of" proved the converse direction but I had a question in the end:

**Here is my proof for $(\Leftarrow)$:**

Suppose $\xi:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{T}$ is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}))-$measurable.  Then by hypothesis, for any elementary cylinder $E$, we have $\xi^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{F}$.

In particular, let $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the elementary cylinder defined by $$E:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:x_{t_{1}}\in B, x_{t_{2}}\in\mathbb{R},\cdots,x_{t_{n}}\in\mathbb{R}\},$$ has the preimage 
\begin{align*}
\xi^{-1}(E)&=\{\omega\in\Omega:X_{t_{1}}(\omega)\in B, X_{t_{2}}(\omega)\in\mathbb{R},\cdots, X_{t_{3}}(\omega)\in\mathbb{R}\}\\
&=X_{t_{1}}^{-1}(B)\cap X_{t_{2}}^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\cap\cdots\cap X_{t_{n}}^{-1}(\mathbb{R})\\
&=X_{t_{1}}^{-1}(B)\cap\Omega\cap\cdots\cap\Omega\\
&=X_{t_{1}}^{-1}(B).
\end{align*}

But by hypothesis $\xi^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{F}$, so we must have $X_{t_{1}}^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$. Since this holds for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we are able to conclude that $X_{t_{1}}$ is measurable.

We can do the similar things to each $X_{t_{i}}$ by just using $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ at $i^{th}$ coordinate and using $\mathbb{R}$ at all other coordinates.

Thus, each $X_{t_{i}}:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and thus $X$ is a stochastic process.

**The question I had is:** my argument only showed $X_{t_{i}}$ is measuralble for finitely many of $t_{i}$, but a stochastic process $\mathbb{T}$ is not necessarily finitely indexed, i.e $\mathbb{T}$ may have infinite indices, for instance $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}_{+}$. **How could I adapt my proof to such a case? or I am having a misconception here so my current proof is okay?**

Thank you so much!

**Edit 1:**

Since it seems that I asked a trivial direction and said I could show the harder direction, I think it is better to post my proof of $(\Rightarrow)$.

Suppose $X:\mathbb{T}\times\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a stochastic process. Recall that a stochastic process $\{X_{t}:t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ leads to the mapping $\xi:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ which maps an outcome $\omega\in\Omega$ to the corresponding trajectory of the process, namely $\{t\mapsto X_{t}(\omega)\}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}.$

This mapping is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}))-$measurable, since the preimage of any elementary cylinder $$E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:x_{t_{1}}\in B_{1},\cdots, x_{t_{n}}\in B_{n}\},$$ is given by $$\xi^{-1}(E)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X_{t_{1}}(\omega)\in B_{1}, \cdots, X_{t_{n}}(\omega)\in B_{n}\}=X_{t_{1}}^{-1}(B_{1})\cap\cdots\cap X_{t_{n}}^{-1}(B_{n}).$$ But by hypothesis, each $X_{t_{i}}:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and thus $X_{t_{i}}^{-1}(B_{i})\in\mathcal{F}$ for each $i$, and thus so is their intersection.

Therefore, $\xi^{-1}(E)\in\mathcal{F}$.

Thus $\xi$ is $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}))-$measurable, as desired.

Comment: You claim in the comments of my answer that you already knew how $\Rightarrow$ goes but were not sure how $\Leftarrow$ goes. This is suspicious because the first implication is hard and the second one is trivial. In fact, the proof you wrote is correct and it shows that each $X_t$ is measurable (this is a rather lengthy proof of $\Leftarrow$). What you don't understand then? What is the definition you know of stochastic process? It usually is defined as a family of random variables (i.e., for each $t,$ $X_t$ is measurable).

Comment: @WillM. It is indeed true that I know how to $(\Rightarrow)$ even though it is hard, and $(\Leftarrow)$ is trivial. The confusion I had was: I indeed showed each $X_{t}$ is measurable, but I only showed finitely many of them, for instance, in my proof, I showed $X_{t_{1}},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}$ are all measurable, but $\mathbb{T}$ may contain infinitely many of indices right? for instance $\mathbb{R}^{+}$? I don't know if I expressed my confusion correctly... (Yes we have the same definition).

Comment: @WillM. oh! so I showed it for any $t_{1},\cdots t_{n}$, so I actually include all the indices?

Comment: To prove $\Leftarrow$ all you need to do is to fix $t$ and show $X_t$ is measurable.

Comment: @WillM. okay, I get it. Thank you!

Comment: @WillM. I seems that I need to wait more time to give you the bounty.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $\mathrm{T}$ instead of $\mathbb{T}.$ Consider also a metrisable, separable space $\mathrm{E},$ with Borel $\sigma$-fiel $\mathscr{E}.$ Define $\mathrm{Z} = \mathrm{E}^\mathrm{T}$ and $\mathscr{Z} = \bigotimes\limits_{t \in \mathrm{T}} \mathscr{E},$ the product $\sigma$-field (separability of $\mathrm{E}$ allows deducing that $\mathscr{Z}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\mathrm{Z}$). Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbf{P}).$ We also write $p_t:\mathrm{Z} \to \mathrm{E}$ given by $p_t(z) = z(t) = z_t \in \mathrm{E}$ (the "projection onto $t$th factor" or the "evaluation at $t$th factor").

**Theorem.** A necessary and sufficient condition for a function $X:\Omega \to \mathrm{Z}$ to be measurable relative to $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{Z}$ is that for every $t \in \mathrm{T},$ the function $p_t \circ X = X_t:\Omega \to \mathrm{E}$ should be measurable relative to $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{E}.$

*Proof.* The necessity of the condition is obvious since each $p_t$ is $(\mathscr{Z}, \mathscr{E})$-measurable. To prove the sufficiency we have to show that for every $\mathrm{G} \in \mathscr{Z}$ the inverse image $X^{-1}(\mathrm{G})$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}.$ Denote then by $X^{-1}(\mathscr{Z})$ the set of all $X^{-1}(\mathrm{G})$ as $\mathrm{G}$ runs on $\mathscr{Z}.$ Thus, we aim at showing $X^{-1}(\mathscr{Z}) \subset \mathscr{F}.$ Denote by $\mathscr{Y}$ the set of all $\mathrm{G} \in \mathscr{Z}$ such that $X^{-1}(\mathrm{G}) \in \mathscr{F}.$ The fact that $\mathscr{Z}$ is the product $\sigma$-field means that $\mathscr{Z} = \sigma(p_t^{-1}(\mathrm{L}); \mathrm{L} \in \mathscr{E}, t \in \mathrm{T}).$ The hypothesis give $X^{-1}(p_t^{-1}(\mathrm{L})) = X_t^{-1}(\mathrm{L}) \in \mathscr{F},$ thus $\mathscr{Y}$ contains $p_t^{-1}(\mathrm{L})$ for $t \in \mathrm{T}$ and $\mathrm{L} \in \mathscr{E}.$ It also easy to see that $\mathscr{Y}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Thus $\mathscr{Y} = \mathscr{Z}.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: could you modify your proof a little bit to keep our notations and definitions the same? Thank you

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay.. do you think the proof I gave is correct?

Comment: What you prove is the necessity, which I mentioned was obvious (it is just taking the composition of two measurable functions). The harder part is to start with the family of random variables and show that the random object (a $\mathrm{T}$-indexed vector) is measurable relative to the bigger $\sigma$-field. That is not trivial.

Comment: Yes I know how to show the $(\Rightarrow)$, I just don't know if my proof for $(\Leftarrow)$ is correct.

Comment: I think you are confused: $\Rightarrow$ is hard, $\Leftarrow$ is trivial.

Comment: I just posted my proof for $(\Rightarrow)$. Sorry for my confusing confusion :(...